# Bootstrap counters in multiple columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, counter

I'm looking for a bootstrap code snippet to implement the animated incremental counters shown at the end of [this template](http://startit.select-themes.com/app-presentation/).

[image]

I searched bootstrap code snippet websites but failed to find anything similar. Could somebody please advise on how to have such counters implemented or where to find a code snippet for that?

Comment: https://codepen.io/dmcreis/pen/VLLYPo might be helpful. https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/ if you are finding a plugin

Answer (score 1):

ScrollMagic/GSAP plus [this plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Animating-Numbers-Counting-Up-with-jQuery-Counter-Up-Plugin.html) might work.